# Extent Report overwriting category and only shows from last test

Tags: java, selenium, testng, extentreports

I'm trying to create an Extent Report with several categories, this in combination with testng. But everytime I run several classes it will overwrite the last category and in the end I will only have the last category. Is there any way I can prevent this?

followin method is run in the @BeforeMethod and here I will init my test

```
private void setupReportBeforeTest(Method method){
    Test test = method.getAnnotation(Test.class);
    String author = "ABC";
    String description = "Test";
    try{
        description = test.description().split(",author:")[0];
        if (test.description().contains(",bug:")){
            author = test.description().split(",author:")[1].split(",bug:")[0];
            this.setJiraBug(test.description().split(",author:")[1].split(",bug:")[1]);
        }else {
            author = test.description().split(",author:")[1];
            this.setJiraBug(null);
        }

    }catch (Exception e){       }

    logging = extentReports.createTest(this.getTestName() + "-" + method.getName(),description)
        .assignCategory(test.groups())
        .assignAuthor(author).pass("Test");
}
```

I'm getting the groups information from the following:

```
@Test(groups = "Testgroup1",description = "Test1,author:Steve")
```

Answer (score 0):

you may assign these Categories not in this setupReportBeforeTest() but in another function when tests are finished and you will have collected every groups in a table.

```
public void assign ( String[] testCategory)
        reportTest.assignCategory(testCategory);
```